# Check a string flag

Tags: ruby

I have a flag `moto`, which is supposed to be a string `'true'` or `'false'`.

How I can check with rspec whether `moto` is either of those strings?

I tried this:

```
context '#modify_moto_for' do
  it "modifies moto flag" do
    xml = RequestModifier.new.modify_moto_for(load_trx_content('sale'), 'false')
    xmlref = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
    moto = xmlref.search("moto").first.text
    puts moto
    expect(moto).to be_in([false])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If it returns a string like 'true' and 'false', you can use

```
expect(moto).to eq('true') #=> or eq('false')
```

I think it does not work here because you return a string and false is a boolean value.

If you return a boolean, you can use

```
expect(moto).to be_true #=> be_false
```

check (be_falsey and be_truthy) to in the rspec docs that gives more powerful checking, Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

A minimum fix is to change:

```
expect(moto).to be_in([false])
```

to something like:

```
expect(moto).to be_in(["false"])
```